# Различные события в CustomControl

Tags: wpf, xaml

Есть CustomControl как на картинке. 
Как сделать, чтобы каждый прямоугольник этого контрола обрабатывал свое событие?
К примеру, я нажимаю на зеленый прямоугольник появляется окно, на красный — прямоугольник меняет цвет и т.д.

Generic.xaml:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Red"/>
                        <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Blue"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Green"/>
                        <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="LightSkyBlue"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD: Или же для таких случаев нужно использовать UserControl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у прямоугольников есть имена, можно сделать как-то так:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="PART_RectangleRed" Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Red"/>
```

И в коде контрола:

```
private Rectangle _rectangleRed;

public override void OnApplyTemplate() {
    if (_rectangleRed != null){
        _rectangleRed.MouseLeftButtonDown -= OnRedClick;
    }

    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    _rectangleRed = GetTemplateChild("PART_RectangleRed") as Rectangle;
    if (_rectangleRed != null){
        _rectangleRed.MouseLeftButtonDown += OnRedClick;
    }
}
```

Но вообще, по моим прикидкам, Custom Control имеет больше смысла там, где внешний вид, возможно, может быть переопределён в дальнейшем (при переопределении Template нужно будет не забыть использовать те же имена, хотя ничего критичного иначе не произойдёт, есть проверка на `null`). Если же вид меняться не будет, можно использовать и UserControl. Хотя вроде как он медленее.

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```
<Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="Red" MouseLeftButtonDown="OnRedClick"/>
```

```
void OnRedClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // код смены цвета прямоугольника
}
```

Comment: Но как сделать, чтобы в Generic.xaml были видны события из файла с кодом? Натыкаюсь на сообщения о том, что к словарю ресурсов нужно создать одноименный файл с расширением *.cs. Нужно ли это делать в случае работы с Custom Control?

Comment: @maxwell: А, действительно, перепутал. Если у вас code-behind, то вам нужен скорее UserControl.